# Access jQuery node's children and its values using PHP to enter into db

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms, dynamic

Can anyone please help me out in this problem. I am in real trouble and I don't know how to go ahead with this.

I have a `tr` tag which contains multiple `div` tags in it. 
Whenever user clicks on a 'Add' link, the same `tr` gets cloned with an incremented id and appended to the table. 
Now, I want to enter everything under each `tr` into the mysql database using php. I really don't know how to do this.

The hierarchy is like this:
`tr-->td-->div(many)-->input fields(many) like chkbox,textarea,radio,input`

The deadline for my project is nearing and I am really stucked upon this.

Comment: What have you tried? What does your code look like? Sounds like something you want to do with AJAX.

Comment: Dave, please can you just put at least an example of the html, without script on the post or on a fiddle so we can try and help you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t2HHh/1/

Comment: Here, I removed so many div sections below it and also when I click on Add, it doesn't add the cloned thing below the same. But, its working in my file.

Comment: Is there any way you can remove the tables within then top-level `<tr>`'s?

Comment: can you please explain what are you trying to say?

Comment: If you are able to change the html you can add a form for easier submission.  Have a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2bWMz/ it'll give you an idea of being able to serialize the "form"  It'll allow you to perhaps loop over all the parameters at the PHP server-side and save them into the DB.

Comment: I got what you are trying to say, but as I said this will be too difficult for a dynamic form like this, since it contains not just 2 questions as shown but more than 50 and there may be such questions where you can add field dynamically. Finally, there can be many such set of questions.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using serialize to get the values of the input fields?

you should be able to do something like $('tr:selected').serialize()

It'd be easier to help if you had some kind of jsfiddle as an example of your problem.

Comment: I will create in a few minutes... Thanks. But, I don't know how to use this serialize function in php and how we will have tr selected.

Comment: serialize is a jquery function, not a php function. http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: how to get valued of input fields? Because on 'onLoad event' there will be only 1 tr, but user might add so many after that. so, how to call that jQuery serialize function using php

Answer (score 0):

Since your question doesn't contain any code, I can't be certain but I would start by getting all the `<tr>`'s and then loop through each of those and get all the input values for that tr_id and add them to an array or json structure.  Then you can serialize that and send it via Ajax to PHP to save.

```
// Initialize an empty array
returnValues = new Array();
$('tr').each(function(index, tr){
    $('input, textarea, checkbox, select', this).each(function(index, input){
        // collect the name and value pairs
        name = input.attr('name');
        value = input.val();
        //now add these into the array.
        returnValues[tr.attr(id)][name][value];
     });
});
// now post the array to php via Ajax
```

Comment: Hey Rob, I am not getting what you are trying to sat. I am kind of new to jQeury, but can you please explain me in detail. I am trying to put my code on jFiddle, but not getting what I want. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I see is to give your input fields appropriate names.  Then you just handle the form submission like any other.

You can set the input names as arrays to get around this.
For example:

```
<input type="text" name="fieldname[]" value="" />
```

Then in your POST data in PHP, $_POST['fieldname'] will be an array.

Comment: like there will be more than 50 input fields under each 'tr'. It will be a total mess if I try to change 'id' of everyone when I clone the 'tr'. Moreover, some of the input fields will be dynamic in itself i.e. you can click on '+'sign besides it and add multiple of them, where again I am using what you said above.

Comment: You can incorporate the row id in the field name as you add them dynamically if that helps you.

Comment: I am not adding them dynamically, but I am cloning the entire 'tr', incrementing it's id by 1 and then appending it to the table.